# How to transfer ArrayList to another activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have next data class

```
data class LegendWrapper(
    val data: List<PlayerPerformance>? = emptyList()

)
data class PlayerPerformance(val name: String, val value: Int, val key: String)

data class TestList(val name: String, val data: LegendWrapper)
```

which I fill with data from Map

```
for((key, value ) in data.legends.all){
recList.add(TestList(key, value))
}
```

Further, by clicking on the name from the recyclerView, I want to transfer this list to another activity. How can I do it ?

i tried to do it like this

```
 heroesAdapt = HeroesRecyclerAdapter(this, recList){
   testList -> val heroesStatsActivity = Intent(this,HeroesStatsActivity::class.java)
   heroesStatsActivity.putExtra("nicknameHeroes", testList.name)
   heroesStatsActivity.putExtra("data", testList.data.toString())
   startActivity(heroesStatsActivity)
}
```

But I get on another screen just a line with which I cannot work

Comment: this is my problem too

Comment: @amin mahjoob see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass any data type other than primitive data, you should pass with `putParcelable`.

Follow these steps:

First, add the `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin to your `build.gradle` app.

*build.gradle.kts*

```
plugins {
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
}
```

Next, make your data class `Parcelable` like this:

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class LegendWrapper(
    val data: List<PlayerPerformance>? = emptyList()
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class PlayerPerformance(
    val name: String,
    val value: Int,
    val key: String
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class TestList(
    val name: String,
    val data: LegendWrapper
) : Parcelable
```

And now you can put Parcelable into intent:

```
heroesAdapt = HeroesRecyclerAdapter(this, recList) { testList -> 
    val heroesStatsActivity = Intent(this, HeroesStatsActivity::class.java)
    heroesStatsActivity.putExtra("nicknameHeroes", testList.name)
    heroesStatsActivity.putExtra("data", testList.data)
    startActivity(heroesStatsActivity)
}
```

In the activity that receives the intent, you get the data as follows:

```
val nickNameHerors = intent.getStringExtra("nicknameHeroes")
val data = intent.getParcelableExtra<LegendWrapper>("data")
```

Comment: I have no such function **putParcelabe** I was able to transfer simply **putExtra**  But then when getting in the second activity when calling val test = intent? .Extras? .GetParcelable ("data") I get an error ***Not enough information to infer type variable T***

Answer (score 0):

use `bundle.putParcelable`

for receive data in other activity use : `bundel.getParcelable`

Comment: I still get a type mismatch error. Could you give more usage example?
```bandle.putParcelable("data", testList.data)```  Type mismatch.
Required:
Parcelable?
Found:
LegendWrapper